# Photon number representation of a position eigenstate

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, harmonic-oscillator, quantum-optics

I wanted to calculate the photon number representation of a position eigenstate, so I developed as follows.

\begin{align}
\vert x\rangle 
=\sum_{n}\vert n\rangle\langle n\vert x\rangle
=\sum_{n}\psi_{n}(x)\vert n\rangle,
\end{align}
where 
\begin{align}
\langle n\vert x\rangle=\psi_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^{n}n!}}\left(\frac{1}{\pi^{1/4}}\right)e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^{2}}H_{n}(x)
\end{align}
with a Hermite polynomial $H_{n}(x)$. From the normalization condition, i.e., $\langle x\vert x\rangle=1$, I would expect to see 
\begin{align}
\sum_{n}\vert \psi_{n}(x)\vert^{2}=1,
\end{align}
but I failed.

**Q.** Did I make any mistake above? or am I completely wrong?

Comment: The expression $\langle x|x\rangle$ cannot be equal to 1. $|x\rangle$ is not normalizable a la Born. Instead, it is more customary to assume $\langle x|x'\rangle=\delta(x-x')$.

Comment: I don't understand this question. Photons do not have position eigenstates - they are relativistic objects without a good position operator. What exactly is the set up here that you think you have a photonic position state, and why are the "photon number" states Hermite polynomials?

Comment: @JánLalinský oh, yes. You’re right. By the way, is the above expansion valid?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Sorry that The question was not so clear. I was asking more about things that come out of the canonical quantization, in which there are an excitation number state (corresponding to photons in optics) and a canonical quadrature operator x. I meant the projection of the eigen state of the quadrature operator x to the excitation number state. I hope this is now clear.

Comment: @JánLalinský : “position eigenstate” is a perfectly standard terminology in quantum optics, even if the “position” is not the position of anything real, but the position of the particle in the harmonical oscillator canonically equivalent to the mode of the electromagnetic field currently considered.

Comment: @FrédéricGrosshans that may be true, but does that make anything I wrote wrong? Or were you replying to ACuriousMing's statement that photons do not have eigenstates?

Comment: [See WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Completeness_relation).

Comment: @JánLalinský I also think Frédéric wanted to reply to ACuriousMind, not you.

Comment: @JánLalinský : I wanted to reply to both of you, but more specificaely to a comment of you advocating the use of the term of “phonon” intead of “photon” when positions are involved. This comment was not wrong per se, but I thought it was driven by a misunderstanding of the context. However,  I don’t see this comment anymore...

Comment: @FrédéricGrosshans I am not sure why my comment has disappeared. In optics context "photon" would be ordinary use, but if $x$ represented position of an atom, then "phonon" would be better.

Answer (score 3):

Your expansion,

> \begin{align}
> \vert x\rangle 
> =\sum_{n}\vert n\rangle\langle n\vert x\rangle
> =\sum_{n}\psi_{n}(x)\vert n\rangle,
> \end{align}
>   where 
>   \begin{align}
> \langle n\vert x\rangle=\psi_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^{n}n!}}\left(\frac{1}{\pi^{1/4}}\right)e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^{2}}H_{n}(x)
> \end{align}
>   with a Hermite polynomial $H_{n}(x)$

is indeed correct. (And, if you want to push in that direction, you might find [this old paper of mine](https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.5724) interesting.)

However, the position eigenstate $|x\rangle$ is not normalizable, so attempting to set
$$
\langle x| x \rangle = 1
$$
will only end in disaster. The normalization for position states is instead normally chosen via a delta-function normalization $\langle x| x' \rangle = \delta(x-x')$ (which seems to be the normalization that's required for your result to be true, if I remember the formulas correctly). As such, what you expect is to have something like
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}2^{n}n!}
e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^{2}-\frac{1}{2}x'^{2}}
H_{n}(x)H_{n}(x')
= 
\delta(x-x')
,
$$
where the product of orthogonal polynomials inside the sum is normally called the Christoffel-Darboux kernel for the polynomial family.